# FreeMarker template - Double sorting

Tags: freemarker

I am working on FreeMarker template for creating chart outputs using HighChart and we have a requirement to do double sorting based on 2 different columns.

Example: *Sorting country list using 2 different columns "Region" and "Country"*

I checked other forums and found double sorting has been defined within array elements as specified below but not at an individual element level.

```
current.children?sort_by('type')?sort_by(['properties','cm:name'])
```

Here is the code snippet

```
<#--Assign the array values-->

<#assign country = country +  [ {
    "category":"${level1}",
    "value":level1Value?number,
    "color": color?string,
    "superRegion":"${level3?upper_case}",
    "region":"${level2?upper_case}"
} ] >
```

Sorting the list - The below double sorting doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this double sorting ?

```
<#list country?sort_by("superRegion")?reverse?sort_by("region") as countrySorted>
```

Comment: Hi, I have filled a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FREEMARKER-61) that could help you.

Answer (score 2):

`?sort_by` can't sort by a composite "key" (as of 2.3.23). Applying `?sort_by` twice just re-sorts the whole list.

Usually, lists should be sorted before passing them to the template anyway. I'm not sure if that's feasible in your case. If not, you can still write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` for it and put that into the data-model etc. (Plus I have made a note that `?sort_by` should be able to do this, since it already exists anyway... maybe some contributor will pick it up.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Applying ?sort_by twice is not working for me and it is throwing an error. Is there a way to make it work? If you know the syntax, can you share with me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is (and your syntax was correct), but as I said, applying `?sort_by` for the 2nd time will just re-sort the *whole* list, which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: hi, Thanks again. Can you provide me an example for double sorting using the TemplateMethodModelEx

Answer (score 2):

Resolved case like this. Using sort_by function twicely won't help you. I resolved this way: list, filter, sort_by. Here example.

Can be checked here: https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Template:

```
Sorted by gender:
<#list humans?sort_by("gender") as h>
   <#if !(genders??)>
      <#assign prevGender = h.gender />
      <#assign genders = h.gender + "---" />
   </#if>
   <#if prevGender != h.gender>
      <#assign genders = genders + h.gender + "---" />
   </#if>
   <#assign prevGender = h.gender />
   index: ${h.index}, gender: ${h.gender}, name: ${h.name}, age: ${h.age}.
</#list>
Sorted by gender, name:
<#list genders?split("---") as g>
   <#if g?? && g?trim!="">gender: ${g}</#if>
   <#list humans?filter(x -> x.gender = g)?sort_by("name") as x>
      index: ${x.index}, gender: ${x.gender}, name: ${x.name}, age: ${x.age}.
   </#list>
</#list>
```

Data model:

```
humans=[{"index":0,"gender":"male","name":"Bazil","age":34},{"index":1,"gender":"male","name":"Serhio","age":33},{"index":2,"gender":"male","name":"Andrew","age":32},{"index":3,"gender":"male","name":"Arty","age":34},{"index":4,"gender":"male","name":"Alex","age":33},{"index":5,"gender":"female","name":"July","age":30},{"index":6,"gender":"female","name":"Anna","age":31},{"index":7,"gender":"female","name":"Tatiana","age":32}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite your list:

```
<#assign mylist = mylist?sort_by("ID") />
<#assign mylist = mylist?sort_by("TYPETRAITEMENT") />
<#assign mylist = mylist?sort_by("DOMAINEMETIER") />
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort_by` with an array as argument is something else. It sorts by nested fields. For instance:

```
orders?sort_by("customer", "last_name")
```

would sort the orders by the customer's last name. (`orders?sort_by("customer.last_name")` would be more intuitive, but it *doesn't work*).

Calling `sort_by` multiple times *does* work when done the correct way. You have to sort by the last sorting field first.

```
country?sort_by("region")?sort_by("superRegion")
```

When sorting by `superRegion`, countries are already sorted by `region`, which is relevant for all those countries with the same `superRegion` value. It's a bit counterintuitive, but it works.